# reading continuous data stream from thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, stream

I have two class each have a single thread. The thread1 from class1 generate data continuously and then alert the thread2 from class2 to read data.

1. my question is what is the best structure to store data in? (because the data is very big and includes more than 50million points where each point contain X Y and Z coordination field).
2. what is the best way to alert the thread2 that "data is ready now for you to read".

thank you every body

Comment: See about producer-consumer structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem